# What does `platform` indicate in Podfile for iOS project?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podfile, deployment-target

Is it different from the `deployment target` for the iOS project? If yes what's the difference between them?

Comment: it's generally best to include the links you read before and go into detail of why it didn't help you find your answer

Answer (score 1):

Platform indicates for which platform the pods project should be generated. 

Platform can be:

- **ios** for iOS projects
- **osx** for MacOS projects
- **tvos** for TvOS projects
- **watchos** for WatchOS projects

Target specifies for which target the libraries need to be linked.

You can read [Podfile Syntax Reference](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#podfile) for more details.

Comment: I'd also add that a given Xcode project may have multiple targets e.g. iOS app and watchOS app and they may not have the same pod requirements.